# Как создать метод в java возвращающий значение тип данных которого не определен

Tags: java

**Задача**: создать метод возвращающий значение, тип данных которого не определен. Метод может вернуть число или строку. **Вопрос**: как это сделать одним методом? Не смог найти решение в гугле.

С переменными такая-же задача: метод может принимать на вход две переменных, обе из которых могут быть или числом или строкой. Ранее писал в нестроготипизированных языках, а с java такой затык)

**Update**: поразмыслив, пришел к выводу, что с методом вопрос решаемый - можно число приводить к строке и возвращать в обоих случаях строку. А вот с определением переменных вопрос открыт)

Comment: Надо посмотреть задачу более детально.. Пока это походит на использования дженериков

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, есть две переменных a и b. Эти переменные инициализируются после того, как пользователь введет данные. Пользователь может ввести число или строку.

Comment: Храните как строку. ПОльзователь вводить строку - это главное. Можте он не хочет вводить 123 как число. До тех пор пока пользователь нерешит, что ему нужно достать число - ничего делать не надо. Если мы изначально знаем что он вводит число или строку - то тоже ничего делать не надо

Comment: Если у вас не валидации - вы получите то что имеете. ПОлзователь может написать и "Двадцать пять" а потом удивляться почему там не число храниться

Comment: можете добавить пример вашего кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение, если не брать во внимание возможность использовать String для данной задачи - использовать тип данных `Object`, сравнивать типы через `instanceof` и использовать преобразование для доступа к методам.

```
// Получаем значение переменной из функции.
Object variable = getValue();
        
// Проверяем, является ли variable строкой.
if(variable instanceof String)
    System.out.println(
        // Преобразовываем variable к String и используем методы класса.
        ((String) variable)
            .replaceAll("t", "g")
    );
else
    // Преобразовываем variable к int и складываем.
    System.out.println((int) variable + 2);

...

// Функция, возвращающая рандомно String или int.
public Object getValue() {
    return new Random().nextBoolean() ? 1 : "test";
}
```

Соответственно, результат выполнения кода рандомно либо `gesg`, либо `3`.

Можно посмотреть в сторону `Generic` и `Reflection`, но добавиться динамической типизации простым путём и без всяких обработок всё равно не выйдет)